# Showing [ Errors were found during POM generation ] while installing Oracle JDeveloper

Tags: java-8, weblogic12c, jdeveloper

I'm encountering an error while attempting to install Oracle JDeveloper Studio (V998593-01.exe). When I search for a solution online, I keep finding links that require access to My Oracle Support, which I don't have. I've set my Oracle home directory, which was created during the installation of Oracle WebLogic Server (Weblogic 12.2.1) previously. Can someone assist me in resolving this issue? Thank you in advance.

**[install screen]**
[image]

**[error screen]**
[image]

**[log]**

> oracle.sysman.nextgen.NextGenInstallerException: java.lang.Exception:
> oracle.sysman.oii.oiif.oiifb.OiifbEndIterateException:
> com.oracle.cie.gdr.maven.PomException: Errors were found during POM
> generation. Please check the logs for more information.   at
> oracle.sysman.nextgen.impl.NextGenInstallerImpl.execute(NextGenInstallerImpl.java:471)
> at
> oracle.sysman.nextgen.impl.NextGenInstallerImpl.execute(NextGenInstallerImpl.java:428)
> at
> oracle.as.install.engine.modules.install.action.AbstractNextGenInstaller.start(AbstractNextGenInstaller.java:214)
> at
> oracle.as.install.engine.modules.install.action.NextGenAPIInstallManager.launchOUI(NextGenAPIInstallManager.java:104)
> at
> oracle.as.install.engine.modules.install.InstallModule.launchOUI(InstallModule.java:165)
> at
> oracle.as.install.engine.modules.install.InstallModule$1.run(InstallModule.java:262)
> Caused by: oracle.sysman.oii.oiif.oiifb.OiifbEndIterateException:
> java.lang.Exception:
> oracle.sysman.oii.oiif.oiifb.OiifbEndIterateException:
> com.oracle.cie.gdr.maven.PomException: Errors were found during POM
> generation. Please check the logs for more information.   at
> oracle.sysman.oii.oiic.OiicInstallAPISession.doOperation(OiicInstallAPISession.java:465)
> at
> oracle.sysman.nextgen.impl.NextGenInstallerImpl.execute(NextGenInstallerImpl.java:452)
> ... 5 more Caused by: java.lang.Exception:
> oracle.sysman.oii.oiif.oiifb.OiifbEndIterateException:
> com.oracle.cie.gdr.maven.PomException: Errors were found during POM
> generation. Please check the logs for more information.   at
> oracle.sysman.oii.oiic.OiicInstallAPISession$OiicActionsThread.run(OiicInstallAPISession.java:936)
> Caused by: oracle.sysman.oii.oiif.oiifb.OiifbEndIterateException:
> com.oracle.cie.gdr.maven.PomException: Errors were found during POM
> generation. Please check the logs for more information.   at
> oracle.sysman.nextgen.actions.PostFeatureInstallPhase.performAction(PostFeatureInstallPhase.java:395)
> at
> oracle.sysman.nextgen.actions.ComponentInstallPhase.doOperation(ComponentInstallPhase.java:353)
> at
> oracle.sysman.oii.oiif.oiifb.OiifbCondIterator.iterate(OiifbCondIterator.java:161)
> at
> oracle.sysman.oii.oiif.oiifw.OiifwInstallPhaseWCCE.doOperation(OiifwInstallPhaseWCCE.java:1072)
> at
> oracle.sysman.oii.oiif.oiifb.OiifbCondIterator.iterate(OiifbCondIterator.java:161)
> at
> oracle.sysman.oii.oiif.oiifw.OiifwActionsPhaseWCDE.doOperation(OiifwActionsPhaseWCDE.java:675)
> at
> oracle.sysman.oii.oiif.oiifb.OiifbLinearIterator.iterate(OiifbLinearIterator.java:134)
> at
> oracle.sysman.oii.oiic.OiicNextGenInstallAPISession$OiicNextGenAPISelCompsInstall.doOperation(OiicNextGenInstallAPISession.java:437)
> at
> oracle.sysman.oii.oiif.oiifb.OiifbCondIterator.iterate(OiifbCondIterator.java:161)
> at
> oracle.sysman.oii.oiic.OiicInstallAPISession.doInstallAction(OiicInstallAPISession.java:653)
> at
> oracle.sysman.oii.oiic.OiicInstallAPISession.access$000(OiicInstallAPISession.java:93)
> at
> oracle.sysman.oii.oiic.OiicInstallAPISession$OiicActionsThread.run(OiicInstallAPISession.java:927)
> Caused by: com.oracle.cie.gdr.maven.PomException: Errors were found
> during POM generation. Please check the logs for more information.    at
> com.oracle.cie.gdr.maven.PomProcessor.processPendingPOMs(PomProcessor.java:1260)
> at
> oracle.sysman.nextgen.actions.PostFeatureInstallPhase.performAction(PostFeatureInstallPhase.java:383)
> ... 11 more

Comment: If you / your company has a license for JDeveloper Studio ... you should be able to get a My Oracle Support account; see https://support.oracle.com/knowledge/registration.html.  If you don't, well good luck.  It would be imprudent of people here to help you install a software that you are not entitled to run!

Comment: @StephenC Understood. I will verify whether any licenses have been purchased.